# How to use entityform and ajax_form_entity in a modal window?

Tags: 7, ajax, javascript, entities

Just getting started with the [entityforms module](https://drupal.org/project/entityform) (and it looks sweet!).  I want to create a 'contact us' link that displays the form in a modal window, submits and then closes the window.

There is a related module, [ajax_form_entity](https://drupal.org/project/ajax_form_entity), that looks like it would help make a clean submission.  The demo site has a 'Views popup integration' section, but that doesn't look useful (or relevant, actually).

Anyone know how I can do an ajax submit of an entity form from a popup?

Answer (score 3):

There is a sandbox module called Modal Entity Forms https://drupal.org/sandbox/andreymaximov/2058521

It depends on the [Modal Forms](https://drupal.org/project/modal_forms) module and will work in the same way, but for entity forms. I have tested the module and it works fine for now, although I want to submit 1 or 2 patches to extend it's functionality.

**EDIT:**
There is now a new module called Modal operations: https://www.drupal.org/project/modal
It's currently dev only (still better than sandbox) and so far it seems to work fine.